# Как пофиксить ошибку c++?

Tags: c++, функции, математика, шаблоны-с++

Недавно начал изучать c++, одно из заданий было:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал код, но вместо нормального ответа он стал выводить:

```
-nan(ind)
```

Я понимаю, что это значит, что у меня под корнем отрицательное значение, но я не понимаю, как оно получается, если всё возводится в квадрат.
Подскажите, в чём ошибка и как пофиксить код?
Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>

T Sigma_Array(const T* array, int count)
{
    T sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; count++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    T average = sum / count;

    T square_s = 1. / count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; count++)
    {
        T difference = array[i] - average;
        square_s *= pow(difference, 2);
    }

    return sqrt(square_s);
}


int main()
{
    float array_1[5] = {0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.0};

    cout << Sigma_Array(array_1, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Comment: Забавное условие — "для целочисленного и вещественного (float и double) массивов". Какой грамотей писал?...

Comment: @Harry Может, это означает - и для целых, и для float и для  double

Comment: @MBo Для целочисленного она в общем случае не даст верного результата...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте вспомним математику и выполним небольшое преобразование:

[image: S^2=\frac{\sum{(x_i^2-2x_i \overline{x}+\overline{x}^2)}}{N}=\frac{\sum{x_i^2-(\sum{x_i})^2/N}}{N}=\frac{N\sum{x_i^2}-(\sum{x_i})^2}{N^2}]

Теперь нужно пройтись по массиву только один раз... Запишем код для `double`:

```
double Var(double* arr, size_t N)
{
    double x2 = 0, x = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        x2 += arr[i]*arr[i];
        x += arr[i];
    }
    return sqrt(N*x2-x*x)/N;
}
```

Теперь просто расширим его в шаблон для `float` и `double` с использованием концепта `floating_point`:

```
template<floating_point Double>
Double Var(Double* arr, size_t N)
{
    Double x2 = 0, x = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        x2 += arr[i]*arr[i];
        x += arr[i];
    }
    return sqrt(N*x2-x*x)/N;
}
```

Собственно, это всё...

Впрочем, можно еще один вариант, если передавать именно массив, то аргументом можно сделать ссылку на массив:

```
template<floating_point Double, size_t N>
Double Var(Double(&arr)[N])
{
    Double x2 = 0, x = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        x2 += arr[i]*arr[i];
        x += arr[i];
    }
    return sqrt(N*x2-x*x)/N;
}
```

и тогда при передаче массива не нужно передавать его размер...

P.S. Ах да, ваш код...

```
template <typename T>  // Ой. Сюда можно передать что угодно, например, int...
T Sigma_Array(const T* array, int count)
{
    T sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; count++) // ЗАЧЕМ ВЫ УВЕЛИЧИВАЕТЕ COUNT?!!!
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    T average = sum / count;
    // Что вы делаете дальше?

    T square_s = 1. / count;  // Откуда это?

    for (int i = 0; i < count; count++) // ЗАЧЕМ ВЫ УВЕЛИЧИВАЕТЕ COUNT?!!!
    {
        T difference = array[i] - average;
        square_s *= pow(difference, 2); // Какое произведение?!
    }
    return sqrt(square_s);
}
```

Хотите в два прохода - так делайте это правильно:

```
template <typename T>
T Sigma_Array(const T* array, int count)
{
    T sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) sum += array[i];
    T average = sum / count;
    T square_s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        T difference = array[i] - average;
        square_s += difference*difference;
    }
    return sqrt(square_s/count);
}
```

Comment: Формулы лучше рисовать на непрозрачном фоне, так как на тёмной теме не видно.

Comment: @maestro И за это минус? :) Как mathurl.com дает, так и я даю... Каким сервисом тогда лучше пользоваться?

Comment: Не подскажете что именно вы сделали с значением среднего арифметического в втором преобразовании?

Comment: Просто подставил вместо него сумму x_i, деленную на N — это значение от i не зависит, а потому может быть вынесено за знак внешней суммы.

Comment: Спасибо!ещесимв

Comment: @Harry, я не ставил минус. А на marhurl можно выбрать формат изображения? Других сервисов я не знаю.

Comment: @maestro Увы, PNG as is, а возиться чтобы ему фон менять — ну, сами понимаете...

Comment: https://latex.codecogs.com/ - сделал с помощью этого сервиса.